# iOS - UICollection view with resizable cells on scroll with CompositionalLayout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout, uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout

I need a collection view with cells that are resizing on scroll as in the screen recording.
I can do this with `Flow layout`, but have no idea how can I achieve this behaviour with `Compositional layout`?

[image: scrolling collectionview]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and review [ask].